# regex only correctly pulling first occurrence

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the column definition for a database table using regexp, but I can't seem to crack it:

This is my expression:

```
(\".*?),\"
```

This is a sample of the table data:

```
"tstamp" DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')) ,"macid" VARCHAR NOT NULL ,"id" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT (null) ,"info" VARCHAR,"temp" DOUBLE NOT NULL , "altemp" DOUBLE, "active" BOOL DEFAULT true, "emailts" INTEGER, "alarmts" INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "algrace" INTEGER DEFAULT 15, 'sid' VARCHAR, 'led' INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 'sends' INTEGER DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY ("macid","id")
```

And this is what I am after:

```
"tstamp" DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
"macid" VARCHAR NOT NULL
"id" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT (null)
...
```

but what I am getting is this:

```
"tstamp" DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
" VARCHAR NOT NULL
" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT (null)
...
```

It appears to be ignoring the start criteria and only the first hit is correct.

What am I doing wrong ?

## Online Regex

http://regex101.com/r/aJ2uW5

Comment: Why it should not match `"temp" DOUBLE NOT NULL`?

Comment: What regex engine/language are you using?

Comment: @anubhava - I only showed the first few matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you want something like this:

```
['"].*?(?=,\s*(?![^)(]*\))['"]|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oM5cL0)

We match one opening quote, then lazily match everything with `.*?` up to a point where our lookahead `(?=,\s*(?![^)(]*\))['"]|$)` is able to assert that the following characters are **either** a comma followed by optional spaces (which are not followed by any number of non-parens characters followed by a closing parenthesis) and a closing quote, **OR** the end of the string (the `$` anchor).

**Is this a mouthful?**

Yes, it is. The visualization and token-by-token walk-through below give you more details, but in my view there is no substitute for building an expression such as this in a full-featured regex tool. That way you see your matches evolve in real time as you create the expression.

**What was wrong with the original?**

Your match actually ate up the following comma and opening quote: `,\"` Therefore after the first match the engine was out of sync with the string.

**Token-by-token explanation**

- Match a single character from the list “'"” `['"]`
- Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) `.*?`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) `*?`
- Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) `(?=,\s*(?![^)(]*\))['"]|$)`

  - Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `,\s*(?![^)(]*\))['"]`

    - Match the character “,” literally `,`
    - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) `\s*`

      - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
    - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) `(?![^)(]*\))`

      - Match any single character NOT present in the list “)(” `[^)(]*`

        - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
      - Match the character “)” literally `\)`
    - Match a single character from the list “'"” `['"]`
  - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `$`

    - Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) `$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GW6u7z523WteHrD-)

Comment: @crankshaft FYI added probable explanation about the original. Also please note that depending on your regex flavor and context you may need to escape the `"` quotes

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried the suggestion, but it did not appear to pull anything at all: http://regex101.com/r/gD6bB1

Comment: @crankshaft Have a look. http://regex101.com/r/gJ5wO8 Seems like a tweak is required on the last one, will have a look.

Comment: Great, yes that's it, now trying to understand how you did it :-)

Comment: `now trying to understand how you did it` Added token-by-token explanation and Debugex visualization.

Comment: Thanks so much, I see that you also spotted that some column names use single quotes and some use double, strange as I would have expected them to be standardized during a dump !

Comment: @crankshaft No worries. Btw I'm surprised your question received so little attention, usually there are four people jumping on every little question. Yours was a lot more interesting. :)

Comment: @zx81 Oh maybe because the problem is a bit complex? Anyways, I was working on this and encountered a [small problem](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16241615#16241615). Here's what I've come up with [**regex**](http://regex101.com/r/nF7mZ3) / [**php**](https://eval.in/146167). Again the OP didn't specify the language :/

Comment: @HamZa Always great to hear from you. I had another idea while in the bath, now sitting down to watch a movie. :) Looking forward to reading your message in detail in the morning (the problem and the solution.) Cheers!

Comment: @HamZa Very clean---define the contexts you don't want, skip them, then match the commas and split. I love how you are using `(?(DEFINE)`---I have been "advertising" it for a couple of years but never thought of good ways to use it. Your ways of using it are inspiring. You are making regex very clean and modular---refactoring expressions. Brililant. Enjoying learning from you. FYI from the PCRE doc `the sequence \g{-1} is a reference to the most recently started capturing subpattern before \g` This works in my tools. I'm sure you know about `(?-1)` but that's a different story. Peace, zx

Comment: I've just discovered a small problem, that I can probably get around in other ways, and that is the ', PRIMARY KEY ("macid","id")' should not be included in the field definitions and would need to be parsed with another regex :-)

Comment: @crankshaft Late and trying to do so much in one regex is asking for bugs, but at the moment `(?<![(])['"](?![,)]|(?:[^")]+"\))).*?(?=(,\s*PRIMARY KEY \([^)]*\)\s*)?,\s*(?![^)(]*?\))['"]|(?1)?$)` will do all of it, though for this level of complexity in what to exclude I would prefer @Hamza 's exclusion-centric solution. Off to bed.

Comment: @zx81 - it's OK, I have parsed it out with a separate regex inside a loop which processes each match. thanks again.

Comment: Credits to @zx81: you could use [this pattern](http://regex101.com/r/fY7zT1) with `preg_split()`

Comment: @HamZa Ha, all credit goes to you and Philip Hazel author of the PCRE library. :)